# update array element mongodb query take too much time

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have collection like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "user_id":"10"
    "movie_rate":[
             {
                rate:2,
                movie_id:"120"
             },
             {
                rate:null,
                movie_id:"230"
             },
    ]
}
```

I want to update movie rate array element with movie id and I build a query for doing this:

```
db.rates.update({
     user_id: data.user_id,
    "movie_rate.movie_id": data.movie_id
}, {
     $set: {
       "movie_rate.$.rate": data.rate
     } 
}
```

All movie id are unique, so there is just one element in the movie rate array that I wanted to update; however my update query take to much time to execute, I have 7000 document and each document have movie rate array which length is 3700.
I found out another solution which in the first place it seems to be very awful idea,I solve this problem in three query first I find document with find query and user id,then I loop over movie rate array and find out the index of that element, I wanted to update next I pull the element from array with movie id and at last I push document in the array with it's position that I found out in the find query my awful solution was significantly faster than the first one.
Here my pull query:

```
db.rates.update(
{
     user_id: data.user_id
}, 
{
    $pull: {
         movie_rate: {
              movie_id: data.movie_id
                     }
         }
}
```

and here is my push query:

```
db.rates.update(
{
     user_id: data.user_id
}, 
{
     $push: {
        movie_rate: {
              $each: [{
                 'rate': data.rate,
                 'movie_id': data.movie_id
               }],
               $position: index
         }

     }
}
```

So why my second solution is faster than my first one?

Comment: Don't you need to use $set in your update query?:
{
    $set: {"movie_rate.$.rate": data.rate}
}

Comment: I also tried with that but  time execution did't change but I update my question